# how to add column to the table from another table by join

Tags: sql, join, rdbms, create-table

I want to add column from another table by join.
I want initial table to be updated with one column from another table. when im doing this it returns me SQL command not properly ended.
I have a query:

```
update final_tableau 
set final_tableau.Mobile_flag = credit_mobile.Mobile_flag
from final_tableau a left join credit_mobile b 
on a.client_pin = b.client_pin
```

Comment: Tag RDBMS. You don't want to add column, you want to update the field value, that's quite different. Try to use alias names in update statement, like `a.Mobile_flag = b.Mobile_flag`

Comment: Try my solution and please reply

Comment: got it! Just made list of pins that i needed and inserted there values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alter table A add column3 datatype
update A 
set column3 = B.column3 
from A inner join B on A.Column1 = B.Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
update final_tableau
  set Mobile_flag= (
               select credit_mobile.Mobile_flag
                 from credit_mobile
                where credit_mobile.client_pin= final_tableau.client_pin
              )
 where exists (
               select * 
                 from credit_mobile
                where credit_mobile.client_pin= final_tableau.client_pin
              );
```